# bitcoinj, unknown confidence level

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I've got a bitcoin address A with its relative encrypted key K stored in a persistence storage.
I am launching bitcoinj through the WalletAppKit class and calling awaitRunning to wait for the blockchain header being downloaded.
I am adding the key pair (A,K) to the wallet after decrypting the key.
I am using the hex of an unspent transaction from the address A and using it as an input for a new transaction with an address B as output.
I am trying to propagate the newly created transaction to the network but i get "Unknown confidence level" message also if the input transaction has many confirmations.

I think the spv blockchain has to be synced after adding address A but i don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried to contact the author of bitcoinj? https://github.com/schildbach

Comment: I asked Mike Hearn and followed his advise to post on the project mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bitcoinj/-Bj3lvM8yFQ

Comment: I changed approach, i am using bitcoinj to create and sign the transaction but not for sending to the network. Thanks to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8475/how-to-get-hex-string-from-transaction-in-bitcoinj i am getting the raw hex format of the transaction and sending it to the network through external services like blockcypher or blockchain

Comment: Be careful to use these kind of API, they have small limits. I recommend you to use the default client.